# Creating and writing/reading from plist file not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am trying to save multiple games and whenever I want to save one the first method is called. However, no matter what I do, `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` keeps telling me that there is no file at `[SaveGameManager filePath]` and `[SaveGameManager savedGames]` keeps giving me nil objects. Any advice/help?

```
@implementation SaveGameManager

+(void)saveGameWithDate:(NSDate*)date type:(NSInteger)type allMoves:(NSArray*)allMoves players:(NSArray*)players playerTimes:(NSArray*)playerTimes delayTime:(double)delayTime useTimer:(BOOL)useTimer delayOption:(NSInteger)delayOption drawOfferState:(NSInteger)drawOfferState resignationState:(NSInteger)resignationState current:(BOOL)current {
    NSLog(@"saving game");
    NSMutableArray* savedGames = [SaveGameManager savedGames];
    if (!savedGames) {
        savedGames = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [@{@"date" : date, @"boardType" : @(type), @"allMoves" : allMoves, @"players" : players, @"delayTime" : @(delayTime), @"useTimer" : @(useTimer), @"delayOption" : @(delayOption), @"drawOfferState" : @(drawOfferState), @"resignationState" : @(resignationState), @"current" : @(current)} mutableCopy];

    if (playerTimes) {
        dict[@"playerTimes"] = playerTimes;
    }

    [savedGames addObject:dict];

    [savedGames writeToFile:[SaveGameManager filePath] atomically:YES];
}

+(NSString*)filePath {
    static NSString* path;

    if (!path) {
        path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedGames.plist"];
    }

    return path;
}

+(NSMutableArray*)savedGames {
    return [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[SaveGameManager filePath]];
}

@end
```

Comment: What's the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:`? What are the objects you're putting into `savedGames`? They all need to be [property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/PropertyList.html) or encoded and then put into `NSData`.

Comment: Ah `writeToFile:atomically:` returns NO and I think it's because I'm adding classes that aren't supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to save a NSDictionary in Plist format in Application document.

```
+ (void)saveSessionToDisk:(NSDictionary *)session {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:session];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *archiveData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedSession.plist"];
    [archiveData writeToFile:fullPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
}
```

Use this code to Load NSDictionary from Plist that you saved earlier.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)loadSessionFromDisk
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SavedSession.plist"];
    DLog(@"%@",fullPath);
    NSFileManager *fileManager =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
        @try {
            NSData *archiveData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
            dict = (NSMutableDictionary*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archiveData];
            if ([dict count] > 0) {
                return dict;
            } else {
                return nil;
            }
        } @catch (NSException *e) {
        }
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Always use this condition before you try to load NSDictionary :

```
if ([[UtilityFunctions loadSessionFromDisk] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [UtilityFunctions loadSessionFromDisk];
}
```

Comment: Ah so you just turn everything into NSData. That's smart.